# Is there a possibility to fix a form that worked before, now that i pasted it into another form it wont work?

Tags: c#, winforms

Some weeks ago i wrote a windows forms program that converts URLs into IPs (THE PROGRAM WORKED PERFECTLY FINE). Now i wanted to paste the code from that form into a new form but surprisingly nothing happens when i press the "convert" button (see screenshots: [old program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOQhM.jpg), [new program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCSWg.jpg))

Comment: May be the new code would have been more interesting being the one you have problems with... But any way, did you bind the buttons' click events to the pasted methods?

Comment: wait ill show the new code

Comment: yea i was playing around with the converting process. I had to put in the array to filter out the ipv6 addresses. thats why its still in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event handlers (`button1_Click`, `button2_Click`) are not wired up automatically if you copy/paste them. In the form select a button, go to the properties window, switch to events view by clicking the flash icon and on the `Click` event line, select your event handler from the combo box. Do this for both buttons.

Another time, give your buttons speaking names (in the `Name` property, not the `Text` property) like `restartButton` or `convertButton` before double clicking them to create the event handler. You will get methods named `restartButton_Click` and `convertButton_Click`. This makes the code easier to understand.